# javascript events - watir-webdriver chromedriver not working?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to test Javascript events with watir-webdriver, which seem to all work fine within Firefox and IE however I'm having problems with Chrome.

```
browser.span(:class, 'over').fire_event "onmouseover"
```

The line above seems to cause the script to break. I am using the latest chrome webdriver (19.0.1068.0) and my gems are up to date.

the chrome log file says: Script execution failed.

Comment: What happens if you do `browser.span(:class, 'over').hover`

Comment: that worked! Thank you, however does this show there is a bug with the chrome driver when using fire_event?

Comment: I do not know. You should ask at chrome driver mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```
browser.span(:class, 'over').hover
```

Comment: follow up, I did some testing etc. And found fire_event is not broken but if you for example have an alert bound to a event and processed to fire it with this method you will encounter a run time error. Example     

`<span class="over" onmouseover="alert('gi');">`

only within chrome though, if you use hover alerts are not a problem.

Comment: still sounds like something that ought to be reported to the chromedriver folks, especially if it works in FF and IE

Comment: will do, just thought I'd share my findings.. cheers for all the help guys.